# how to know if oracle http server is installed or not?

Tags: oracle, server

how to know if oracle HTTP server is installed or not ? i am trying to check in my system if oracle HTTP server is installed or not in my machine ?

Comment: _"how to know if oracle HTTP server is installed or not"_ **installed** or **running** ?

Comment: installed and running both.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some system diagnostic steps to see if you have something Oracle installed:

First, Oracle HTTP Server is just a Apache HTTP server, so you will largely depend on seeking some Oracle specific environment variables and components.

On **Linux**:

I would start with checking if env. variable ORACLE_BASE exist. `echo $ORACLE_BASE`, or similar.

Two, look for existence of the `/etc/oraInst.loc`.

See if you can locate *opmnctl*. (`locate opmnctl`).

On **Windows**, look for `C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory`.